# Displaying Error not found after successful deployment on Google Appengine

Tags: maven, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Even though I have deployed my spring-boot app successfully on Appengine, it shows 'Error: Not found'.
My appengine-web.xml is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <service>default</service>
  <version>8</version>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="default" value="jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?useSSL=false&amp;cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=${user}&amp;password=${password}" />
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I used reactjs for client project and all working fine in local.The api_base_url has been changed as

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'https://tonerproject-224917.appspot.com/api';
```

But still having the problem. Please, can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to dig into this issue, it could be better that you may open a new support ticket with Google Cloud Platform [1], so that the scenario can be better studied, since this seems to be a specific issue for your App Engine configuration.

This will help to have a direct view to your scenario and dig into those errors you are facing so that they can be deeper investigated in order to find the root cause.

I f you could attach a screenshot with the error message you are facing as well as further logging for this issue would be very helpful.

In the meantime, I would like to suggest trying your request (or confirm if you have done so) as described in the official documentation [2]:

```
@WebServlet(name = "requests", description = "Requests: Trivial request", urlPatterns = "/requests")
public class RequestsServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
  }
}
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-handled

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Once you have the required reputation you may post comments and ask clarification from the author or suggest creating a support ticket.